# Should I dispose copies of StreamReaders/Writers

Tags: c#, system.io.directory

So I have a class that has a StreamReader as a variable. The StreamReader is set through the constructor. When I use this class, I make a StreamReader outside of the class and pass it through. I then dispose the StreamReader instance that I passed through the constructor of the class. Do I need to dispose the StreamReader instance inside the class?

Code:

```
private class Class1
{
    private StreamReader Reader;

    public Class1(StreamReader Reader)
    {
        this.Reader = Reader;
    }
}

private class Class2
{
    public void Test()
    {
        StreamReader Reader = new StreamReader(@"");
        Class1 Test = new Class1(Reader);
        Reader.Dispose();
        //Do I need to dispose the Reader in Class1 aswell?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing the 1 instance of `StreamReader` into your `Class1` instance. It does not create a copy, it passes a reference of that existing `StreamReader`. If you were to call `this.Reader.Dispose();` in your instance of `Class1` you would be calling it on the exact same instance of `StreamReader` that you can created in the `Test()` method.

So the answer for this block of code is **No**, there is no need to call `Dispose` again on that same instance.

Comment: Ok so I understand that I can call dispose in the constructor of class1 and I wont have to call it again because its a reference, but the variable in Class1 is a copy isn't it?

Comment: @JacksonTarisa - no, it is not. It is a pointer to the exact same instance. The constructor takes a pointer to a `StreamReader` instance.

Answer (score 1):

There is only one `StreamReader` instance in your code, which is referenced from different variables (3 including the argument in the constructor), and disposing it once is enough.

However, ***your code won't work*** if you need the `StreamReader` inside `Class1` after you call `Reader.Dispose();` because the one inside `Class1` is the same one, and will have been disposed as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a method that uses an IDisposable, which is no longer required once the method terminates, then you should use a `using { ... }` block within that method, but if you pass the IDisposable to your method, then you either need to wrap the call to the method with a `using { ... }` block, or manually call `.Dispose()`.